# What's wrong with my JSON?

Tags: json

Anybody out there notice anything wrong with this JSON? It validates at JSONLint.com, but neither Chrome nor Firefox's native JSON parse functions will properly parse it.

Any ideas?

```
{
        "result": "{\"players\":[{\"name\":\"User 522\",\"turn\":true,\"score\":0},{\"name\":\"User 925\",\"turn\":false,\"score\":5}],\"enableControls\":false}",
        "error": "null",
        "id": "7"
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't parse it either, it doesn't look nice.

Comment: Where is this JSON coming from? A server? Or are you creating it in JavaScript to pass to another JavaScript function?

Comment: It's coming from a server. It's being produced by org.json, the Java library from json.org.

Comment: I tested this by having my server send back the exact same thing and it parsed no problems in Chrome...What are you getting back? A string?

Comment: So what's the exact error? The JSON looks right to me and seems to parse ok on my end

Comment: Chrome says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. 
I get this JSON to JavaScript as a string. It has the slashes in it when I put in it JSON.parse(). I'm not using an XHR, I'm using Web Sockets for the transmission.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the EXACT string that is being returned that you would like to parse.

Comment: Alright then, I only get that error when putting in that JSON string as a string literal in JavaScript. I guess your problem is an escaping problem like Jerome WAGNER's answer

Answer (score 3):

Even though you json looks kind of weird, it conforms with the json specification.

You problem comes from an escaping problem when defining literals in Firefox or Chrome. The "\" (backslash) character needs to be escaped with a backslash.

Example 1:

```
JSON.parse('{"key":"\""}'); breaks
```

Example 2:

```
JSON.parse('{"key":"\\""}'); works
```

So JSONLint.com is right, and Firefox is right and Chrome is right also.

You would not hit this problem if you were testing through an ajax request, because the escaping would be handled automatically. You are hitting the problem because you want to feed the json string as a literal (hence the need for escaping)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jerome WAGNER: I think the \ is only in there to escape the quotes.

Comment: The json standard imposes double quotes around values. So if you want a double quote in a json string value, you need to escape it with a backslash. This is for the json side of the problem. Now when you input a literal single-quoted string into firefox, backslash needs to be escaped with a backslash. Who doesn't love escaping ?

Comment: Curious: 
'{"result":"{\"players\":[{\"name\":\"User 522\",\"turn\":true,\"score\":0},{\"name\":\"User 925\",\"turn\":false,\"score\":5}],\"enableControls\":false}","error":"null","id":"7"}'.replace('\','');

Produces "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" 

The same error I get when I try to use JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

I see now what is happening. `result` is itself an embedded json string.

Let me regroup and answer again.

Your server is not doing you any favors here.

Again, the string as given will NOT parse thus is not a valid JSON string. And I don't see a way to  massage it to get it to parse.

Are you SURE that this is the string that is being returned or perhaps this is a visualization of the string from a debugger?

<strike>That is not valid JSON text, that is a somewhat mishappen JavaScript literal.</strike>

You do not parse a literal, you parse text to obtain a literal.

Your literal would be better represented as...

```
var obj = {
    result: {
        players: [{
            name: "User 522",
            turn: true,
            score: 0
        },
        {
            name: "User 925",
            turn: false,
            score: 5
        }],
        enableControls: false
    },
    error: null,
    id: 7
};
```

and this is the equivalent JSON text. Try parsing this..

```
var json = '{"result":{"players":[{"name":"User522","turn":true,"score":0},{"name":"User925","turn": false,"score":5}],"enableControls":false},"error":null,"id":7}';
```

Comment: should be a comment.  JSON is a string representation of a JavaScript object, it's rather common for questioners to post without the string delimiters.  It doesn't make the question any less valid.

Comment: @Andy - thanks for that. :-\  I was in the process of explaining. And whether or not it is common to mis represent a data structure does not make it inappropriate to point out the difference.

Comment: @Sky: you expanded your answer, so downvote removed (as per my downvote removal policy, paragraph 23 line 7 ;-)).  Indeed, it's not inappropriate to point out the difference, but it is more appropriate to use comments for such a thing :-)

Comment: "That is not JSON" is wrong as it is JSON. It's perfectly in keeping with the JSON specs which even say to escape double quotes in strings

Comment: @Bob: actually, he's right.  JSON should be a string, and without the curly braces wrapped with string delimiters it's just a plain JavaScript object literal.

Comment: The poster just didn't show the string part, which is fine. If you're going to show pure JSON it's silly to show it encased in quotes as that forces it into the context of some language. In the OP comments it says this JSON is coming from a server, so is likely a string

Comment: It's coming from the server as a string.

Comment: @Ronald, if the server is returning that exact string to you, the server is faulty. There is no practical way to parse that string. I suspect that there is more to this.